# What's equipment can I use to move a dual 4k workstation into a machine room?

Tags: kvm, 4k

I've got a film editing workstation that I currently run in my studio. It's a noisy box, and generates lots of heat, so I'm looking to move the hardware into a machine room around 50-100 ft of cable away from the studio.

From the computer I run dual 4k monitors (each at 3840x2160, from displayport). On top of the dual-head computer monitors, at my desk I have a keyboard and mouse. I also have video and audio (for the edited video) coming out of the editing card over SDI for video and balanced XLR for audio. I can run the SDI video and XLR audio over that distance, but I'd like a recommendation about the right product to use to extend the dual-head 4k monitors (and keyboard, mouse and USB) over that kind of distance.

Can anyone recommend an extender or KVM that I can use to remote dual 4k monitors (running at 2x 3840x2160)  from a workstation about 50 to 100 ft away?